# Passing client userid to Oracle when using a pooled connection

Tags: oracle, connection, connection-pooling

Our company has an audit requirement to track individual user interaction with the application by user id. We use **Tomcat 7** with the Tomcat connection pool and an **Oracle 11.2 database** (soon to be 12c). We connect using a Type 4 datasource managed by JNDI on the server which uses a system user id. Users log on using SSO to the web application. We want to make sure that whenever a user modifies a database record, their SSO signon id instead of the system id is used in an audit column to identify who made the modification.

My research shows that using `getClientInfo` and `setClientInfo` may be the way to go and I want to be clear on how I would implement this. Would I use the `setClientInfo` on the pooled datasource Connection to set the client user id, or run the Oracle stored procedure `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO` to pass the client user id? I know that in the Oracle virtual table `v$session` there is a column for `OSUSER` that holds this information. How do I get it there? Could I make a direct update to that column?

Since this is a multi-threaded application server, I don't want to end up with a concurrancy issue.

Comment: `osuser` is going to be the operating system user running Tomcat.  It's not going to be the application user.  Using the `dbms_application_info` to get and set the information is certainly a reasonable approach.  You could also use a context (presumably a secure application context).  Or you could use proxy authentication (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:21575905259251).

Comment: My preference would be to use the setClientInfo of the Connection interface to pass the user id to Oracle. The problem is, this is a Properties file and I need to know the supported property name. I thought it would be OCSD.CLIENTID, but that is not being recognized. Is there something that needs to be configured in the JDNI Datasource to allow this setting?